# Custom function, value from pipeline

Tags: powershell

This a function for changing local user password on a remote machine. I'd like to make it work with a value from pipeline. This works:

```
    $x= @()
    $x += Set-UserPassword -ComputerName smz0017d -User localadmin -NewPassword "1"
    $x += Set-UserPassword -ComputerName smz0027d -User localadmin -NewPassword "2"
    $x | Out-GridView
```

But with value from pipeline it doesn't. Any tips?

```
    $x = @()
    $x += [pscustomobject]@{
        ComputerName   = 'smzmi0027d'
        User           = 'localadmin'
        NewPassword    = 'djkufdjkuf1234'
    }
    $x += [pscustomobject]@{
        ComputerName   = 'smzmi0027d'
        User           = 'localadmin'
        NewPassword    = '1'
    }
    
    foreach ($y in $x)
    {
            $y | Set-UserPassword
        
    }
```

The function to accept value from a pipeline. It invokes command on a remote machine and builds custom object with a result:

```
function Set-UserPasswordLocaly
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
        [string]$User,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 1)]
        [string]$NewPassword
    )
    
    #TODO: Place script here
    try
    {
        Set-LocalUser -Name $User -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString $NewPassword -AsPlainText -Force) -ErrorAction Stop
        $pwdSetResult = "$user password has been changed"
        $isSuccess = $true
    }
    catch
    {
        $pwdSetResult = ($_.Exception).Message
        $isSuccess = $false
    }
    return [PSCustomObject]@{
        'ComputerName'     = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        'isSuccess'        = $isSuccess
        'Message'          = $pwdSetResult
        
    }
}

function Set-UserPasswordRemotely
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
        [string]$ComputerName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 1)]
        [string]$User,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 2)]
        [string]$NewPassword
    )
    
    #TODO: Place script here
    $param = @{
        ComputerName     = $ComputerName
        ScriptBlock      = ${function:Set-UserPasswordLocaly}
        ArgumentList     = $User, $NewPassword
        ErrorAction      = 'stop'
    }
    try
    {
        $invoke = Invoke-Command @param
        $invokeResult = $invoke.Message
        $isSuccess = $invoke.isSuccess
        
    }
    catch
    {
        $invokeResult = ($_.Exception).Message
        $isSuccess = $false
    }
    
    return [PSCustomObject]@{
        'ComputerName'      = $ComputerName
        'isSuccess'         = $isSuccess
        'Message'           = $invokeResult
        
    }
}

function Set-UserPassword
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
        [string]$ComputerName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                   Position = 1)]
        [string]$User,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                   Position = 2)]
        [string]$NewPassword,
        [Parameter(Position = 3,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]$PasswordVersion
    )
    
    #TODO: Place script here
    PROCESS
    {
        if ($env:COMPUTERNAME -eq $ComputerName)
        {
            Set-UserPasswordLocaly $User $NewPassword
        }
        else
        {
            Set-UserPasswordRemotely $ComputerName $User $NewPassword
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have no provisions for passing the computername in the pipe.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Ah my mistake. Fixit. Now it works! Thank you so much

Comment: "with value from pipeline it doesn't." - well, what _does it do_? Throw errors? Behave unexpectedly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ComputerName` parameter in `Set-UserPassword` is not configured to accept pipeline input. Change that and it'll work:

```
function Set-UserPassword
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
        [string]$ComputerName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                   Position = 1)]
        [string]$User,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                   Position = 2)]
        [string]$NewPassword,
        [Parameter(Position = 3,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]$PasswordVersion
    )

    # I'm using Write-Host to demonstrate binding behavior, replace with your actual code
    process { Write-Host $PSBoundParameters }
}
```

```
PS ~> [pscustomobject]@{
>>   ComputerName = 'smzmi0027d'
>>   User         = 'localadmin'
>>   NewPassword  = '1'
>> } |Set-UserPassword
>>
[NewPassword, 1] [User, localadmin] [ComputerName, smzmi0027d]
```